# Merge the data of 2 files based on a common column

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to merge 2 files based on 1st column 348.csv & 349.csv when joining them using below command

> join -a1 -a2 -1 2 -2 2 348.csv 349.csv

not getting a proper output i.e. getting messed up output.

cat 348.csv:

> ```
> Timestamp                   BRM Servers 
>                               348  
> 1/28/2013 02:00 AM PST        176  
> 1/28/2013 02:30 AM PST        150
> 1/28/2013 03:00 AM PST        140
> 1/28/2013 03:30 AM PST        100
> ```

cat 349.csv:

> ```
> Timestamp                   BRM Servers
>                                349  
> 1/28/2013 02:00 AM PST         99
> 1/28/2013 02:30 AM PST         115
> 1/28/2013 03:00 AM PST         101
> 1/28/2013 03:30 AM PST         78
> ```

expected is below:

> ```
> Timestamp                   BRM Servers 
>                              348  349 
> 1/28/2013 02:00 AM PST       176  99 
> 1/28/2013 02:30 AM PST       150  115 
> 1/28/2013 03:00 AM PST       140  101
> 1/28/2013 03:30 AM PST       100  78
> ```

and in an order.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You say "based on 1st column", but your `join` command is working with second column... Is that a typo, or oversight, or even the problem you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{i=NF<5?"__":$1$2$3$4;a[i]=$0;next} FNR==1{print}{i=NF<5?"__":$1$2$3$4}FNR>1&&i in a{print a[i],$NF}' file1 file2
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  head f1 f2
==> f1 <==
Timestamp                   BRM Servers 
                              348  
1/28/2013 02:00 AM PST        176  
1/28/2013 02:30 AM PST        150
1/28/2013 03:00 AM PST        140
1/28/2013 03:30 AM PST        100

==> f2 <==
Timestamp                   BRM Servers
                               349  
1/28/2013 02:00 AM PST         99
1/28/2013 02:30 AM PST         115
1/28/2013 03:00 AM PST         101
1/28/2013 03:30 AM PST         78

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{i=NF<5?"__":$1$2$3$4;a[i]=$0;next} FNR==1{print}{i=NF<5?"__":$1$2$3$4}FNR>1&&i in a{print a[i],$NF}' f1 f2
Timestamp                   BRM Servers
                              348   349
1/28/2013 02:00 AM PST        176   99
1/28/2013 02:30 AM PST        150 115
1/28/2013 03:00 AM PST        140 101
1/28/2013 03:30 AM PST        100 78
```

Comment: The above solution not giving proper output.                                                             `sh-3.00$ awk 'NR==FNR{i=NF<5?"__":$1$2$3$4;a[i]=$0;next} FNR==1{print}{i=NF<5?"__":$1$2$3$4}FNR>1&&i in a{print a[i],$NF}' dm_eai_348.csv eai_349.csv`                                                        >                                                     `Timestamp             BRM Servers
02/04/2013 09:21          5 349
02/04/2013 09:21          5 7
02/04/2013 09:21          5 7`
>

Answer (score 0):

I assume your file is tab separated. If not, the spaces in "column 1" are going to make this task much harder.

```
sed 1q 348.csv
join -t $'\t' -j 1 -o 0,1.2,2.2 <(sed 1d 348.csv) <(sed 1d 349.cvs)
```

gives tab-separated output that looks like:

```
Timestamp       BRM Servers 
        348     349  
1/28/2013 02:00 AM PST  176     99
1/28/2013 02:30 AM PST  150     115
1/28/2013 03:00 AM PST  140     101
1/28/2013 03:30 AM PST  100     78
```

Comment: ,getting below error                                                `sh-3.00$ join -t $'\t' -j 1 -o 0,1.2,2.2 <(sed 1d eai_js_348.csv) <(sed 1d eai_js_349.csv)`
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your files are tab separated

```
join -a1 -a2 -1 1 -2 1 -t $'\t'  348.csv 349.csv
```

Comment: the above join command adding the contents of 349.csv after 348.csv. what i want is mentioned above in "expected is below".

Comment: The result you get using this command is the same you said in your "expected is below"

`Timestamp BRM Servers  BRM Servers 
 348   349
1/28/2013 02:00 AM PST 176   99
1/28/2013 02:30 AM PST 150 115
1/28/2013 03:00 AM PST 140 101
1/28/2013 03:30 AM PST 100 78`